# How many Dominion sets are there?

Tags: dominion

How many Dominion sets are there? List them all? Including base set, expansions, special, etc. Additionally, how many promo cards are there, and list those as well?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of February 2024, there are 16 sets and 12 promo cards<sup>1</sup>.

In release order:

- Dominion (Base game)
- Intrigue
- Seaside
- Alchemy
- Prosperity
- Cornucopia
- Hinterlands
- Dark Ages
- Guilds
- Adventures
- Empires
- Nocturne
- Renaissance
- Menagerie
- Allies
- Plunder

A new expansion called Rising Sun will be coming in 2024.

And the list of Promo cards:

- Envoy (November 2008)
- Black Market (March 2009)
- Stash (February 2010)
- Walled Village (June 2011)
- Governor (October 2011)
- Prince (June 2014)
- Summon (November 2015)
- Sauna/Avanto (September 2016) <sup>2</sup>
- Dismantle (December 2017)
- Church (2019)
- Captain (2019)
- Marchland (2024)

Separately there is also the Dominion Base Cards product; which includes the treasures and victory cards you need to play any setup of Dominion; without including any Kingdom cards. This allows players to purchase just an expansion without needing the base game, and allows 5-6 player games.

Guilds and Cornucopia, each being half-sized expansions, are currently only sold as a combined Guilds & Cornucopia set.

Dominion Base Game, Intrigue, Seaside, Prosperity, Hinterlands, and Cornucopia & Guilds each have both a first and second edition, with the second edition for each removing some cards and adding different ones. Due to some cards being different; you could count first edition and second edition as separate sets. Upgrade packs including just the new cards were released for each second edition. Other sets have received minor updates in later printings; but nothing as big as brand new cards.

Note that all sets through Guilds were planned as part of the original design of Dominion; while Adventures and beyond were created later due to Dominion's popularity.

All information taken from http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com.

<sup>1</sup> "Cards" is used here to refer to all promos including Summon, even though Summon is an Event, not a Card, within the rules of Dominion.

<sup>2</sup> Sauna/Avanto is a split pile; counted here as 1 card even though it is technically 2 separate cards.

Comment: There's also the Kingdom Dominion set, which is a stand-alone demo version of the game, featuring a selection of cards from various sets.

Comment: Interestingly, I can only find it on boardgamegeek in its Dutch release: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/184207/het-koninkrijk-dominion

Comment: Is the Dominion Base cards pack also the 5-6 player expansion "kit"?

Comment: @Jontia Sort of. The Base Cards pack combined with the original Dominion or Intrigue will give you enough cards to play 5-6 players. Otherwise there are only enough cards to play any other expansion with 4 players.